# RelativeLayout rules for nested views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-xml

I came across an issue which I don't know how to solve.
I'll picture it using a simple example.

Here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/ttt"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/whiteish" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <View android:layout_below="@+id/ttt"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@color/facebook_gradient_high" >
    </View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result:

[image: Result]

The small blue rectangle is not positioned below the big white square. I undestand that this is happening because the white square is not a direct child of the `RelativeLayout`. However I would like to achieve the desired result. How would I do that?

EDIT:
I also tried applying the margins directly to the `View` without using the `FrameLayout`. This doesn't produce the desired result either, because **I don't want the margins to be taken into account when positioning other views relative to it**.

Answer (score 0):

give your FrameLayout an id like

```
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
```

and place your blue rectangle below the big white one like this

```
android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
```

EDIT: 
just to be clear do you want this as the desired result ?

[image]

Comment: Check my EDIT. This won't work the way I want, because it will take the margins into account. This will happen when I change it from BELOW to ABOVE. The example doesn't picture that but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: how about you add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" to your blue view.